# JavaScript - unhandled exception in skelJs in ASP MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, exception

I tried to use a template HTML5 web site as view of my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. This template is here: http://html5up.net/helios/

Unfortunately I have some problem with this. I tried to put the main frame of these templates on my _layout page. Also I put other parts in index.chtml.

The problem is when I run the program, Visual Studio says there is an unhandled exception in skel.min.js which is:

```
this.insertBefore(b,a.me)
```

My _layout page is here:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery.dropotron.js")"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/skel.min.js")"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/skel-panels.min.js")"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/init.js")"type="text/javascript"></script>

    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/skel-noscript.css")" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style-desktop.css")" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style-noscript.css")" type="text/css"/>
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body class="homepage">

    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="header">

        <!-- Inner -->
        <div class="inner">
            <header>
                <h1><a href="#" id="logo">Helios</a></h1>
                <hr />
                <span class="byline">Another fine freebie by HTML5 UP</span>
            </header>
            <footer>
                <a href="#banner" class="button circled scrolly">Start</a>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <!-- Nav -->
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <span>Dropdown</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Magna phasellus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Etiam dolore nisl</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <span>And a submenu &hellip;</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Phasellus consequat</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Magna phasellus</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Etiam dolore nisl</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Veroeros feugiat</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="left-sidebar.html">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                <li><a href="right-sidebar.html">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                <li><a href="no-sidebar.html">No Sidebar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div>
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Tweets -->
                    <section class="4u">
                        <header>
                            <h2 class="icon icon-twitter circled"><span>Tweets</span></h2>
                        </header>
                        <ul class="divided">
                            <li>
                                <article class="tweet">
                                    Amet nullam fringilla nibh nulla convallis tique ante sociis accumsan.
                                    <span class="timestamp">5 minutes ago</span>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <article class="tweet">
                                    Hendrerit rutrum quisque.
                                    <span class="timestamp">30 minutes ago</span>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <article class="tweet">
                                    Curabitur donec nulla massa laoreet nibh. Lorem praesent montes.
                                    <span class="timestamp">3 hours ago</span>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <article class="tweet">
                                    Lacus natoque cras rhoncus curae dignissim ultricies. Convallis orci aliquet.
                                    <span class="timestamp">5 hours ago</span>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>

                <!-- Posts -->
                    <section class="4u">
                        <header>
                            <h2 class="icon icon-file circled"><span>Posts</span></h2>
                        </header>
                        <ul class="divided">
                            <li>
                                <article class="post stub">
                                    <header>
                                        <h3><a href="#">Nisl fermentum integer</a></h3>
                                    </header>
                                    <span class="timestamp">3 hours ago</span>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <article class="post stub">
                                    <header>
                                        <h3><a href="#">Phasellus portitor lorem</a></h3>
                                    </header>
                                    <span class="timestamp">6 hours ago</span>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <article class="post stub">
                                    <header>
                                        <h3><a href="#">Magna tempus consequat</a></h3>
                                    </header>
                                    <span class="timestamp">Yesterday</span>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <article class="post stub">
                                    <header>
                                        <h3><a href="#">Feugiat lorem ipsum</a></h3>
                                    </header>
                                    <span class="timestamp">2 days ago</span>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>

                <!-- Photos -->
                    <section class="4u">
                        <header>
                            <h2 class="icon icon-camera circled"><span>Photos</span></h2>
                        </header>
                        <div class="row quarter no-collapse">
                            <div class="6u">
                                <a href="http://mdomaradzki.deviantart.com/art/Air-Lounge-385212062" class="image full"><img src="../../images/pic10.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u">
                                <a href="http://mdomaradzki.deviantart.com/art/Paris-City-Streets-II-382623606" class="image full"><img src="../../images/pic11.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row quarter no-collapse">
                            <div class="6u">
                                <a href="http://mdomaradzki.deviantart.com/art/Trainride-Visions-383309985" class="image full"><img src="../../images/pic12.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u">
                                <a href="http://mdomaradzki.deviantart.com/art/Paris-Metro-382623851" class="image full"><img src="../../images/pic13.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row quarter no-collapse">
                            <div class="6u">
                                <a href="http://mdomaradzki.deviantart.com/art/Cliffs-of-Coogee-II-366961860" class="image full"><img src="../../images/pic14.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u">
                                <a href="http://mdomaradzki.deviantart.com/art/Stormy-Coast-VII-366561367" class="image full"><img src="../../images/pic15.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>

            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">

                    <!-- Contact -->
                    <section class="contact">
                        <header>
                            <h3>Nisl turpis nascetur interdum?</h3>
                        </header>
                        <p>Urna nisl non quis interdum mus ornare ridiculus egestas ridiculus lobortis vivamus tempor aliquet.</p>
                        <ul class="icons">
                            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-facebook"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-google-plus"><span>Google+</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-pinterest"><span>Pinterest</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-dribbble"><span>Dribbble</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-linkedin"><span>Linkedin</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>

                    <!-- Copyright -->
                    <div class="copyright">
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li>&copy; Untitled. All rights reserved.</li>
                            <li>Design: <a href="http://html5up.net/">HTML5 UP</a></li>
                            <li>Demo images: <a href="http://mdomaradzki.deviantart.com/">Michael Domaradzki</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And the files are in the link I put above.

I tried to contact the programmer of this template (which bases it on an engine, “skelJS”). There isn't any answer yet. How can I fix this problem?

Error details:

```html
    Exception was thrown at line 5288, column 6 in http://localhost:1572/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js
    0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
    Exception was thrown at line 4, column 13743 in http://localhost:1572/Scripts/jquery.min.js
    0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
    Exception was thrown at line 4, column 13957 in http://localhost:1572/Scripts/jquery.min.js
    0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
    Unhandled exception at line 12, column 444 in http://localhost:1572/Scripts/skel.min.js
    0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: NotFoundError
    The program '[10048] iisexpress.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The program '[10048] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing in IE? :)  And yes everybody has that mistake from jquery-1.10.2.min.js.

Put it on a blank page and it is still there. The fault was also there in "jquery-1.8.2"